# Does eternal damnation still exist?

Tags: soteriology, hell

**1 Timothy 2:4 NIV**

> 'God our Savior [sic] who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth'.

Anticipating his suffering and death, Jesus proclaims,

**John 12:31-32 NIV**

> Now is the time for judgment on this world; now the prince of this world will be driven out. And I, when I am lifted upg from the earth, will draw all people to myself.

Do the above verses tell us that, after Jesus saved man, eternal damnation no longer exist?

Comment: Different traditions have very different answers to this question (as different as "yes" and "no", that is!). Also, I think http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/525/biblical-arguments-for-universal-salvation is basically the same question. Can you differentiate this question from that one in some way?